# GraphQL Query Structure to Filter / Aggregate Results from a PostgreSQL Table

Tags: postgresql, graphql, postgraphile

I am new to GraphQL and I am struggling to understand how to access / reference a table in the same logical way that I would approach a normal SQL query. I have created a docker container for postgres and I have initialized the database with a simple table of data.

To create the table, I ran this in my `\init` directory. (Running Windows btw)

```sql
CREATE TABLE fda.nfl (
    "team" TEXT,
    "conference" TEXT,
    "division" TEXT,
    "city" TEXT,
    "wins" INT,
    "losses" INT,
    "ties" INT
);
```

In GraphiQL, I can simply select everything with this query:

```
{
  allNfls {
    edges {
      node {
        team
        conference
        division
        city
        wins
        losses
        ties
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to run something that can aggregate vertically and horizontally, e.g. `sum(losses) as total_losses` or `(wins / (wins + losses + ties)) as win_ratio`. I am unsure how to go about either of those scenarios with GraphQL. I would also need to query on certain conditions, but passing in a column name as an argument to `node` does not seem to work, i.e. `node(team: "Chiefs")` spits back an error about type `allNfls`

Is referencing a Postgres table like this in GraphQL even possible?

Comment: Not directly; their data models are rather different.  You might see what [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) has to offer.  It can be a little better to think about GraphQL as selecting fields and chasing links in a REST API, rather than a query language like SQL: the only sort of “join” or “compute” options are things that the schema author chooses to expose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would need to query on certain conditions, but passing in a column name as an argument to `node` does not seem to work

The standard [filtering plugin](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/filtering/) adds condition arguments to the `allNfls` field, so try

```gql
query {
  allNfls(condition: {team: "Chiefs"}) {
    edges {
      node {
        conference
        division
        city
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, assuming that the team name is a primary key in your table, you should also be able to select the individual team:

```gql
query {
  nfl(team: "Chiefs") { # maybe `nflByTeam`?
    city
    wins
    losses
    ties
  }
}
```

> I want to run something that can aggregate vertically and horizontally, e.g. `sum(losses) as total_losses` or `(wins / (wins + losses + ties)) as win_ratio`. I am unsure how to go about either of those scenarios with GraphQL.

For vertical aggregates, you would need to use the (non-standard) [aggregates plugin](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/aggregates/), with which you could do something like

```gql
query {
  allNfls { # might also use a condition
    sums {
      losses
    }
  }
}
```

The "horizontal aggregate" is a custom [computed column](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/computed-columns/), which you can most easily achieve by writing a Postgres SQL function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fda.nfl_win_ratio(n fda.nfl) RETURNS real
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
AS $$ SELECT n.wins / (n.wins + n.losses + n.ties)) $$
```

For more complicated stuff, you might want to add your own fields to any of the GraphQL types by [writing your own plugin with the help of `makeExtendSchemaPlugin`](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/make-extend-schema-plugin/), which can use the full power of SQL and JavaScript combined.